# thymeleaf how to pass an id from dropdown list to another html

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

buildings is a list and i want to get selected list element id from other html to redirect 
 (/energy/ + building.id) like this

```
                    <div th:each="building: ${buildings}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
                       <span class="d-flex align-items-center">
                          <a class="nav-link target-building" th:data-building-id="${building.id}" href="#" id="topBuildingId">
                          <span class="text-sm" th:text="${'&nbsp; ' + building.name}"></span>
                          </a>
                       </span>
                    </div>
```

and the other html to passed building.id

```
                    <li class="sidebar-subnav-header">energy data</li>                        
                    <li th:class="${menu=='buildings'} ? 'active' : ''">
                       <a th:href="@{'/energy/' + ${building.id}}">
                          <span>energy data</span>
                       </a>
                    </li>
```

then how i can get just a selected index list id ? not to show whole list.

Comment: An expression like `${buildings[0].id}` works just fine.  And you should be able to pass it into your fragment: `th:fragment="menu(..., buildings[0])"` and then use `${building.id}` in your fragment.  Does that help?

Comment: @Metroids sorry that i couldn't write an html name above. in one view different html above, first one is headerTop.html and the other one is left menu.html so they are different html. if i select an dropdown element on headerTop.html so that i can get a selected 'id' on left menu.html as well. thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

Firstly if you want get clicked element id you can achieve this by creating custom js function

```
function getId(id) {
   alert("clicked element id", id);
}
```

Secondly add the function where you need it. In your case:

```
<a class="nav-link target-building" th:data-building-id="${building.id}" href="#" id="topBuildingId" onClick="getId(this.id)">
```

In additionally if you want redirect new page with javascript you can use

```
window.location.href = "URL";
```

Comment: Hi @Anar Rzayev im getting a 'buildings' data like this <th:block th:fragment="menu(..., buildings)"  so i just waaaant to get buildings[0].id(selected Id) to redirect mapping controller mapping @RequestMapping("energy/{buildingId}") not a page redirection